# Excel 2010 add a cell value to an external reference

Tags: excel

I need to add the value in cell A1 to a formula in cell B1 that references an external spreadsheet.  Column A lists workdays of the month (i.e. 09-19-2014, 09-22-2014, 09-23-2014, etc.).  Column B has the following formula which works as expected by calculating headcount based on location and pay type.

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(('C:\Shared\Labor\HC\[09-23-2014.xls]report'!$H$2:$H$500="Location - 12")*('C:\Shared\Labor\HC\[09-23-2014.xls]report'!$G$2:$G$500="Hourly")),NA())
```

What I need to accomplish is instead of specifically using 09-23-2014 I need it to pull the value from column A of that row.  I have tried using evaluate, concatenate, and "& A1 &", but these methods do not pull in the needed value from the external spreadsheet.

There are hundreds of spreadsheets thus eliminating the possibility of them being opened when this spreadsheet is opened.  Does anyone have any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In many years working with excel I never find a possibility to retrieve values from an excel which is not opened. What you can try is to make a VBA code where you open each file, update your values and then close the file. Because it will be quite a lot of code I can't give you an example for this. You can make a list of all paths to the files and let VBA pass them one by one.

Comment: I am able to retrieve values from an excel spreadsheet which is not opened.  The current formula I use is working to do that.  I need assistance, if there is any to be had, with adding the cell value to the external reference.